# How to use Nikic/PHP-parser to extract HTML tags from PHP files

Tags: php, php-parser

Now I need a Visitor to extract the HTML tag from the PHP file.
At first, I thought I would just extract the Value of a Node of type InLineHTML.
Just like this

```php
if ($node instanceof Node\Stmt\InlineHTML)
        {
            self::$result[] = json_encode(utf8_encode($node->value),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        }
```

But I found that only HTML tags outside of PHP tags are considered InLineHTML nodes.
Just like this

```php
<?php
   echo "aaa";
?>
<input name='test' value=''>
```

But then I discovered that I could use echo to output HTML tags in PHP code, and that they would be treated as String_ Node.

```php
<?php
    echo "<input name='test' value='aaa'>";
/*
1: Stmt_Echo(
        exprs: array(
            0: Scalar_String(
                value: <input name='test' value='aaa'>
            )
        )
    )
*/
```

or

```php
<?php
    return '<tr class=tr1><td class=td1 width='.$l.'% align=right>';

/*
0: Stmt_Return(
                expr: Expr_BinaryOp_Concat(
                    left: Expr_BinaryOp_Concat(
                        left: Scalar_String(
                            value: <tr class=tr1><td class=td1 width=
                        )
                        right: Expr_Variable(
                            name: l
                        )
                    )
                    right: Scalar_String(
                        value: % align=right>
                    )
                )
            )
*/
```

In this case, using judgment InLineHTML for judgment is not accurate.
For complete tags in String_, I can use regular expressions to match.
But if the tag is Concat, like `'<input'.'>'`, then this becomes difficult.

How do I use a single Visitor to do the HTML tag extraction

Comment: Generally speaking, I don't think there's a simple reliable way to figure out the output of a PHP script unless you execute the script. I'm curious about what's the exact use case here.